# My dropdown list is too long

Tags: css

My sub-menu dropdown list is too long and I want it to have a "column" type of look instead of just a "top to bottom" list look.....what coding do I need to add or change?  This is how it looks now:

```
.primary-nav ul ul.children li.page_item_has_children:after, .primary-nav-container ul ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after {
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: 6px solid #ccc;
    top: 25%;
    right: 6px;
}

.primary-nav ul li a, .primary-nav-container ul li a {
    padding-bottom: 0.75em;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #888;
    text-transform: capitalize;

    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

.primary-nav ul li a:hover, .primary-nav ul li.current_page_item a, .primary-nav-container ul li a:hover, .primary-nav-container ul li.current_page_item a {
    color: #222;
}

.primary-nav-container ul ul.sub-menu, .primary-nav ul ul.children {
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 125%;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

.primary-nav-container ul:hover li:hover > .sub-menu, .primary-nav ul:hover li:hover > .children {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: visible;
}

.primary-nav-container ul li:hover > .sub-menu, .primary-nav ul li:hover > .children {
}

.primary-nav-container ul ul.sub-menu li, .primary-nav ul ul.children li {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 8em;
    margin: 0.5em 5% 0.5em 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    float: none;
}

.primary-nav-container ul:hover li:hover > .sub-menu li, .primary-nav ul:hover li:hover > .children li {
}

.primary-nav-container ul ul.sub-menu li a, .primary-nav ul ul.children li a {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
}

.primary-nav-container ul ul.sub-menu li > ul, .primary-nav ul ul.children  li > ul {
    top: -38%;
    left: 100%;
```

Thanks,
  Anita

Comment: If you could also supply the HTML, and maybe make it into a JSFiddle, that would be helpful.  Also an example of "column" vs "top to bottom" would be good.  It's unclear what that means.

Comment: Maybe I can explain it better? Once the hover reveals the list, I would like the list to show in multiple columns instead of just one long column that you have to keep scrolling down to the bottom.....here is the site>>> thnx2u.nolongerbroke.ws

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML multiple column select list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203198/html-multiple-column-select-list)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're asking for is the `size` attribute of the `select` element. If specified, it will show [x] number of items with a scrollbar to the right rather than showing a dropdown.

```
<select size="5">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
    <option>Option 5</option>
    <option>Option 6</option>
    <option>Option 7</option>
    <option>Option 8</option>
    <option>Option 9</option>
    <option>Option 10</option>
 </select>
```

**[here is a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/twwb1gtk/)**

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for?  Once the hover reveals the list, I would like the list to show in multiple columns instead of just one column that you have to keep scrolling down to the bottom.....here is the site>>> thnx2u.nolongerbroke.ws